# How to record a multi-host podcast with a dedicated microphone on an iPad

Tags: microphone, recording, podcasts

Trying to get a podcast started with two host that are working remotely. The simple environment I am trying to work with recording with a [discord bot](https://craig.chat/home/). I have a gaming headset that I want to try using and my co host has a Rode VideoMicro. That hardware choice was because we are eventually  going to use that to record video as well down the road.

Podcasts, for now, are easier for us, given the distance. Their prime device is an iPad. While we should be able to connect the mic, I am having issues figuring out how they will hear what I am saying without either....

- Interference from my voice in the mic (if we were to use iPad speakers for sound) or more likely
- The iPad will not be able to split audio output to the speakers and input from the microphone

I realize there is an XY problem here that might be solved with some hardware but I don't really know where to cost effectively start. I would like to use the mic we already invested in if possible

If even possible, is there a way to use that mic with an iPad and record a multiple host podcast?

Answer (score 1):

Welcome to Sound Design.

Your co-host will need to use headphones/earpods, etc to stop your voice interfering with their voice.

You can use a TRRS splitter to combine the microphone and headphone leads. There are plenty around but as you're using a Rode mic they make the [SC6](https://www.rode.com/accessories/sc6) for TRRS inputs or the [SC6L](https://www.rode.com/accessories/sc6-l) for lightning inputs.